# Observable array in Kotlin to know when an array elt value is changed

Tags: kotlin

My goal: I have a simple class with a public

```
val reds = IntArray(10)
val greens = IntArray(10)
val blues = IntArray(10)
val lums = IntArray(10)
```

If someone modifies **any** red value, I'd like to update the lum value.

```
myObj.reds[5] = 100 // Should update myObj.lums[5] = reds[5]+greens[5]+blues[5]
```

The problems is that the `by Delegates.observable` seem to only be used for var objects - nothing mentions "and if you modify an element of an array, here is what gets triggered"

Maybe this isn't possible and I have to do all modifications through getters and setters - but I'd much rather have something trigger like an observable!

Comment: You can't do this _with an array._  You could maybe do it with a `List` or the like, but if you have an object of type `IntArray`, the only thing that will happen when you get or set an element is that you get or set the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a custom class instead, `IntArray` is mapped to primitive `int[]` array so it doesn't provide any place to inject callback - changing value like your example (`myObj.reds[5] = 100`) you only know when array is returned, but have no control over changes after that.

For example you can create class like this:

```
class IntArrayWrapper(size: Int, 
                      val setterObs : ((index: Int, value: Int) -> Unit)? = null){  
    val field = IntArray(size)
    val size
        get() = field.size
    operator fun iterator() = field.iterator()

    operator fun get(i: Int) : Int {
        return field[i]
    }
    operator fun set(i: Int, value: Int){
        field[i] = value
        setterObs?.invoke(i, value)
    }
}
```

Operator functions will let you get values from underlying array with same syntax as if you were accessing it directly. `setterObs` argument in constructor lets you pass the "observer" for setter method:

```
val reds = IntArrayWrapper(10){index, value ->
    println("$index changed to $value")
    invalidateLums(index) // method that modifies lums or whatever you need
}

val a = reds[2] // getter usage
reds[3] = 5  // setter usage that triggers the setter observer callback
reds.field[4] = 3 // set value in backing array directly, allows modification without setter callback
```

Note that this imposes limitations, as you won't be able to freely use `IntArray` extension methods without referencing backing `field` nor will you be able to pass this class as an `Array` argument.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is the cleanest way of solving your problem but, you could use the `ObservableList` ([FX observable collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html)):

```
var numbers: ObservableList<Int> = FXCollections.observableArrayList()
numbers.addListener(ListChangeListener<Int> {
    //Do things on change
})
```

***But as I mentioned, by adding these collections you are mixing FX components into your application, which I do not know if it is wanted or even if it works on various platforms like android!***