# Is it clean/correct to use FXCollections when not using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, collections, kotlin, javafx-8

I was answering a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51975499/observable-array-in-kotlin-to-know-when-an-array-elt-value-is-changed/51980614#51980614), where the solution was to use an observable collection like `ObservableList`. Later I realised that I don't know if the solution is considered as "clean", since using `ObservaleList` from the FXCollections is like using partly JavaFX but at the same time not using it.

Is it ok to use [FXCollections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html) and mixing them with let's say [AWT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html) or in the [Spring framework](https://spring.io) or any other framework which has nothing to do with JavaFX?

I did not find any native observable collection API in Java/Kotlin. Is there a library/framework that contains observable collections and would separate them from JavaFX? I have tried looking them up, but I have only found [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), which has, from what I understood, nothing to do with the behaviour I want.

**To sumarize my question:** Is it considered clean using FXCollections in projects that have nothing in common with JavaFX. If not, is there a framework which would produce the same behaviours as observable collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is *a bit* of a smell. Introducing a dependency towards a specific (large) framework/component, to then only use a small fraction of technology, that should be done "fully conscious".

You always have to balance between **reusing** existing code, or by *writing* it yourself. You shouldn't look at the world like a supermarket, where you walk around and throw whatever thingy into your cart that *looks* helpful or interesting on a first glance. Build tools like maven make that super easy (just add another entry to your POM file, right), but *defining* the dependency is *the smaller* part of this decision! It can have unpleasant consequences later on, down the road.

Having said that, as you are asking about JavaFx specifically, my answer is: avoid doing it.

The problem with JavaFX is: there are plenty of environments that give you trouble when going for JavaFX. I have seen more than once that group A created tooling that was based on JavaFX, to then find that group B couldn't be using that tool because they had to use it on IBM System Z. Sorry, IBM System Z and JavaFX, not a nice story.

Long story short: adding new dependencies to a project needs a clear decision, and you have to make sure that it doesn't cause problems for the people using your delivery. Adding the dependency is done in 5 minutes, but then you made yourself **dependent**, for the life time of your project! And given the sad story of JavaFX, who knows what will happen to it in 1, 3, 5 years.

Comment: I like your point with the dependencies and the “just another entry in my POM file”! What about any open source libraries for observable collections in java/koltin?

Comment: Unfortunately, that question is off topic here. We don't recommend libraries, we only recommend to not use them ;-). Seriously: I don't have a good answer for that request.

Comment: JavaFX is modularized.  If you know what you are doing, you can use and only rely on its [`javafx.base`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.base/module-summary.html) module without the rest of the framework.  The base stuff like observable properties, collections, binding, and events was built to be independent of all the platform-specific graphical stuff in JavaFX (though that fact is not generally well known or utilized).

Comment: The javafx base implementation is likely the best library for such functionality currently available for Java.  Even still, GhostCat's answer is well thought out and argued and still applicable for many applications, so [caveat emptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor)