# Kotlin watch array change

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I'm trying to be notified when an array changes its content.
Through this code I'm able to notify the setting of the array, but nothing happens when a new item is inserted.

```
var array: MutableMap<String, List<String>> = mutableMapOf()
    set(value) {
        field = value
        arrayListener?.notify()
    }
```

The only thing I came up with is resetting the array to itself everytime I add, delete o edit items, like this:

```
array = array
```

I read this question [How to watch for array changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes) relative to Javascript, but I'd like an easier solution then creating a new object, can anyone suggest it?

Comment: Probably not fully related to your question, but if you''re working with Android you could use an [`ObservableList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableList). Otherwise I guess the only solution is to create a subclass of an existing `List` implementation that notifies an `Observer` whenever its content is changed (i.e., added, removed, cleared, ...)

Comment: A rather late addition: If you wish to remain with the Kotlin environment, I have recently created a library with a number of observable collections: https://github.com/theblitz/ObservableCollections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array's API is quite simple: elements can be written there and can be read from an array.

At 99% (a number without justification, read "the vast majority") array's usages people are satisfied with this simple API. It would be a shame if a simple interface with straightforward implementation was mixed with tricky functionality.

Moving to your problem, a possible approach could be create an array's wrapper

```
class ArrayWrapper<T> (private val array: Array<out T>, 
                       private val onChange: () -> Unit) {
    val size = array.size

    fun get(index: Int): T {
        return array[index]
    }

    fun set(index: Int, value: T) {
        array[index] = value
        onChange()
    }
}
```

An example of usage:

```
val ints = ArrayWrapper(arrayOf(1, 2, 3)) {
    println("Array has been changed")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are currently only observing that a new map is assigned to `array` variable. Your code won't notify you if the map entry is added or removed from the map.

If you want to observe if the `array` is reassigned you can use an Observable delegate from Kotlin standard lib.

Note: You should rename `array` variable that it fits a data structure you have used.

Here is an example:

```
 var map:  MutableMap<String, List<String>> by Delegates.observable(mutableMapOf()) {
    property, oldValue, newValue ->  
    if (oldValue != newValue) //notify that reference has changed
 }
```

You can read about observable delegate [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/observable.html).

Since you want to observe changes in the map I think you should take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51975499/observable-array-in-kotlin-to-know-when-an-array-elt-value-is-changed). It might help. To archive what you want, you'll have to extend map or create a wrapper around it which will notify you when a map entry is added or removed.

Comment: Very interesting the Delegates.observable utility.
So, to be notified about changes in the single array of the map (you're right, I confused the name of the variable), I should monitor the inner property of the array.
I tried adding the observable property to the List<String> element, but it doesn't work in one single line, so I have to create a wrapper.